# Yii2: How to access module variable inside the module itself?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm creating a Yii2 Module , 
in this module I set a variable upload_path.
now I'm trying to access this variable from a behavior inside this module using

```
 module = MyModuleClass::getInstance();
```

and I get null ,
the only way to access this variable is by setting the config :

```
'modules' => [
    'w_forms' => [
        'class' => 'wardany\dform\DynamicForm',
        'upload_path'=> "@frontend/web/uploads",
        'upload_url'=> "/uploads",
    ],
]

Yii::$app->getModule('w_forms')->upload_path
```

but I think this is not good cuz user may change the Id 'w_forms'

Comment: This is a design limitation in Yii2. Please check [this issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/14421) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse you will get `null` value.

I think using `MyModuleClass::getInstance();` will create a new instance of your class but yii creates its own instance of the module on the begining of the app.

you can use `$this->upload_path` inside the module.

and using `$this->owner->upload_path` inside the behavior to access its parents properties.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put them in your Application's `Yii::$app->params`.

**Pros:**

- You will always be able to access them even if the Module is not instantiated yet.
- You will be able to access the parameters even from your Module's ActiveRecords.

**Cons:**

- You will need to have a fixed key in your parameters so you cannot configure individual modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit all Controllers from a single controller and add variable to parent controller

Main controller:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\api\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 * Default controller for the `default` module
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public $someVar=255;
}
```

Inherited controller:

```
     namespace frontend\modules\api\controllers;

    class SomeController extends DefaultController 
    {
        public function actionIndex() {
              $someVariable=$this->someVar;
         }
    }
```